# Create a view with JOIN, not working since other table have just few matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

I have a core table named `users`, with a list of users.
some of those users, have a record in a table named `tracker`.

I want to view the `users` table, and add to it a column named `last_call` from `tracker`, so it will be `NULL` if the user does not exist in `tracker`, and if it does, it will show the value.

So the first step is to create a JOIN. I read here I should use LEFT OUTER JOIN, but it did not solve my problem. the below query returns only records for which the user exists on the `tracker` table. if user records doesn't exist, the user is missing from the results.

```
SELECT u.*, fq.last_call FROM tracker fq LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.id = fq.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have the tables backwards.  If you want all rows in `users`, then it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.*, fq.last_call
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     tracker fq 
     ON u.id = fq.user_id;
```